# SQL Query for tables that are not in the list

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I executed this query to fetch all tables-

```
SELECT table_name FROM user_tables
```

This returned 100 results. I now executed this query to fetch a list of tables based on certain condition

```
select distinct table_name
from all_tab_columns
where column_name = 'my_column_id'
order by table_name
```

This returned 66 rows. Is there a query where I can fetch the remaining 34 tables?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select table_name 
from user_tables t
where not exists(
    select table_name 
    from all_tab_columns c
    where column_name='my_column_id' 
    and t.table_name = c.table_name
)
order by table_name;
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `NOT EXISTS` to return every table that does not have a column with that name:

```
SELECT table_name
FROM user_tables ut
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select table_name
                  from all_tab_columns atc
                  where atc.column_name = 'my_column_id'
                    and ut.table_name = atc.table_name)
```

You can also use `EXCEPT` to combine the two original queries:

```
SELECT table_name
FROM user_tables ut
EXCEPT
select table_name
from all_tab_columns
where column_name = 'my_column_id'
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I think your asking use a `UNION ALL` and then do the opposite `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT DISTINCT table_name 
FROM all_tab_columns 
WHERE column_name = 'my_column_id' 
ORDER BY table_name
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT table_name 
FROM all_tab_columns 
WHERE column_name != 'my_column_id' 
ORDER BY table_name
```

Or if you only want the 34 you can use `NOT IN` and use the first query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT table_name 
FROM all_tab_columns 
WHERE table_name NOT IN (SELECT table_name 
                         FROM all_tab_columns 
                         WHERE column_name = 'my_column_id' )
ORDER BY table_name
```

Comment: No, your second option is wrong and will return tables that have the column anyway if the table has more than one column.

Comment: @JohnHC woops. fixed :)

Comment: No need for that DISTINCT in the sub-query.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `not in`

```
select distinct table_name 
from all_tab_columns 
where table name not in
(
select table_name
from all_tab_columns 
where column_name = 'my_column_id'
)
order by table_name;
```

Worth noting, `not exists` is faster, but over a dataset as small as a few thousand rows a `not in` will be fine (and easier to grasp as a concept)

Comment: Even more important, `NOT EXISTS` is also "null-safe". (Many people are surprised by the `NOT IN` behavior if the sub-query returns a NULL.)

Comment: @jarlh `TABLE_NAME` cannot be `NULL` in Oracle's dictionary views.

Comment: If you use `user_tables` in the outer query then you do not need the `DISTINCT` keyword.

Comment: @MT0, it was a general advice, when to use `NOT EXISTS` instead of `NOT IN`!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the data all in one query:

```
SELECT t.table_name,
       CASE WHEN c.table_name IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
         AS has_column
FROM   user_tables t
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       user_tab_columns c
       ON (    t.table_name  = c.table_name
           AND c.column_name = 'MY_COLUMN_NAME' );
```

*(Note: Oracle will, by default, convert table and column names to upper case [to abstract the user from case sensitivity issues] unless you have surrounded them in double quotes; so, you probably want the column name in upper case. Where possible you should avoid using double quotes in queries as it causes confusion.)*

If you just want the non-matching columns:

```
SELECT table_name
FROM   user_tables
MINUS
SELECT table_name
FROM   user_tab_columns
WHERE  column_name = 'my_column_id';
```

Or

```
SELECT table_name
FROM   user_tables t
WHERE  NOT EXISTS ( 
         SELECT 1
         FROM   user_tab_columns c
         WHERE  column_name  = 'my_column_id'
         AND    t.table_name = c.table_name
       );
```

Or

```
SELECT table_name
FROM   user_tables
WHERE  table_name NOT IN ( 
         SELECT table_name
         FROM   user_tab_columns
         WHERE  column_name  = 'my_column_id'
       );
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be generally careful while comparing `USER_TABLES`and `USER_TAB_COLUMNS`  as illustrated below

```
select count(*) cnt from user_tables;

       CNT
----------
         1 

select  count(distinct table_name) cnt
from all_tab_columns
where column_name = 'my_column_id';   

       CNT
----------
         3
```

You see that there are *more tables in `USER_TAB_COLUMNS` than in `USER_TABLES`*

How is it possible?  The view `USER_TAB_COLUMNS`  (contrary of its name) contains also **VIEW** columns, so the simple *arithmetic* (MINUS, NOT IN etc) of the table names between `USER_TABLES`and `USER_TAB_COLUMNS` doesn't always make sense.